# Fail to add pallet-nicks because of version of log

Tags: substrate

I am learning substrate and

I am just following tutorials.

On the second tutorial (https://substrate.dev/docs/en/tutorials/add-a-pallet/import-a-pallet) I can not proceed because of below error.

```
Execution failed (exit code 101).
/Users/~~~/.cargo/bin/cargo metadata --verbose --format-version 1 --all-features
stdout :     Updating git repository `https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git`
    Updating crates.io index
error: failed to select a version for `log`.
    ... required by package `frame-support v3.0.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?tag=monthly-2021-05#70ef0afc)`
    ... which is depended on by `pallet-nicks v3.0.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?tag=monthly-2021-05#70ef0afc)`
    ... which is depended on by `node-template-runtime v3.0.0 (/Users/~~~/projects/substrate-node-template/runtime)`
    ... which is depended on by `node-template v3.0.0 (/Users/~~~/projects/substrate-node-template/node)`
versions that meet the requirements `^0.4.14` are: 0.4.14

all possible versions conflict with previously selected packages.

  previously selected package `log v0.4.13`
    ... which is depended on by `finality-grandpa v0.13.0`
    ... which is depended on by `sc-finality-grandpa v0.9.0`
    ... which is depended on by `node-template v3.0.0 (/Users/~~~/projects/substrate-node-template/node)`

failed to select a version for `log` which could resolve this conflict

stderr :
```

It happens when I added pallet-nicks and features on the runtime/Cargo.toml regarding to the tutorial content.

Until then it's fine.

Comment: I am sorry, but I was not able to reproduce your issue,

here is my rust setup 

`
stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)  
rustc 1.52.0 (88f19c6da 2021-05-03)
`

no problems with `log` crate, when following the tutorial using master branch of the template

Comment: I am using mac and the version of my rustup is rustup 1.24.3.

Answer (score 1):

I found work-around and it was to add log dependency manually on the cargo.toml like below

```
# cargo.toml
log = '^0.4.14'
```

It had been OK but I encountered another issue after next step (it fails to build after configuration) so I just used the answer branch (add-a-pallet-v3.0.0+monthly-2021-05) and it is OK....

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same error. Solved it by this method:
instead of adding: "pallet-nicks = { default-features = false, version = '3.0.0', git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git', tag = 'monthly-2021-05' }" in your cargo.toml, just add "pallet-nicks = { default-features = false, version = '3.0.0'}".

Answer (score 0):

I had not exactly the same error, but in the same tutorial, this occurs due to compatibility issues with updated versions of substrate and the tutorial,
I solved it by making all dependencies compatible within the environment (which you have hopefully built):

```
cargo update
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got it working: https://forum.polkadot.network/t/nicks-pallet-branch-missing/4039/2

Instead of using `pallet-nicks = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }` which doesn't exist

Use the substrate github:

`pallet-nicks = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }`